# Two-way pictorial "riddLe"

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, visual

LOOk at the Ordered images belOw and determine the phrases that they cOllectively represent:

[image]

Hint: It's a person, well, two of them (vertically/horizontally).

---

<sub>Also, some of the images have multiple names (possibly in a common vernacular) for the object being depicted. Just to make it a bit harder.</sub>

Comment: Upvote if you like the idea, for a future puzzle, of a pictorial "crossword" puzzle where instead of letters in a cell, you have to choose from a set of images, some of which don't apply to any "word", so you'd have unused images to throw you off, but you'd still get descriptions for the "words".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Joseph Goebbels and Steven Miller?

The pictures are:

> Down:
>  coffee, aka "Joe"
>  sieve
>  Gir
>  bell
>  s (for a hissing snake)
>  Put together:  Joe-sieve Gir-bell-s
>  Across:
>  s
>  tea
>  Fen(way Park)
>  Miller
>  Put together: S-tea-fen Miller

The connection between these two is:

> apparently they look alike.

Comment: You got the first part right. It's not Steven Weber. I'll give you a hint: The second person looks like the first.

Comment: Ha, ha, ha, yes your recent edit got it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FELVqMA.png

Comment: None of these last more than a day. They're too phonetically easy. Each one needs to have multiple common vernaculars, and the person/place/thing needs to be lesser known. Good job though. :-)